# sql(dr) is sending a missing result

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I transfer the data I have taken from sql to the list, but it sends 1 missing data every time, the sql command works without any problems.
works incorrectly in c#
If there are 10 data in sql, it pulls 9 of them.

```
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("EXEC AnalysisUnitCorrect ", Datacon.baglanti());
        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Analysis s = new Analysis();
                s.UnitName = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);
                s.Correct = Convert.ToInt16(dr[1]);
                AnalysisCorrect.Add(s);
            }

            Datacon.baglanti().Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Datacon.baglanti().Close();
        }
```

Comment: Side point: your connection, command and reader objects need `using`. Do *not* cache the connection object. Also, to execute a procedure efficiently, you can do `using (var komut = new SqlCommand("AnalysisUnitCorrect", baglanti) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if (dr.Read())` line is the problem.  Calling "Read()" advances to the next record.

You can simplify this and just remove the `if` statement and leave the `while` loop.